# Need regular expression for below format with atleast 10 digit allow

Tags: regex

Need regular expression for below format with atleast 10 digit allow.

```
5125636563,
512-563-6563,
(512) 563-6563,
512 563 6563,
021 5252 2522,
44 207 183 8750
```

I have used

```
^\(\d{2,3}\) ?\d{3,4}( |-)?\d{3,4}( )?\d{0,10}|^\d{2,3}( |-)?\d{3,4}( |-)?\d{3,4}( )?\d{0,10}
```

but it is not working correct for atleast 10 digit number and last two format.

Comment: What kind of format is acceptable for you? Can you explain the conditions?

Comment: It's working well for the penultimate format.?? which format.I want it should accept 10 digit.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the problematic cases.

Comment: @SUMANSINGH penultimate matches... https://regex101.com/r/fI9cX5/1

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan- Thank you but it is accepting 8 digit only but I want it should accept atleast 10 digit.

Comment: @SUMANSINGH ugh... please next time do your best in asking questions :)

Comment: @Roko -I ask this in my question it is not working correct for atleast 10 digit number and last two format. :) :)

Comment: Test it with multiple simpler regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may require at least 10 digits with a `(?=(?:[ ()-]*\d){10})` positive lookahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?=(?:[ ()-]*\d){10})(?:\(\d{2,3}\) ?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{3,4} ?\d{0,10}|\d{2,3}[ -]?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{0,10})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF5gV0/3)

Note that the lookahead matches 10 digits (`\d`) that can be preceded with zero or more spaces, `(`, `)` or `-` symbols (`[ ()-]*`).

I also suggest replacing `( |-)?` with a character class `[ -]?`.

Comment: I want to allow space also in starting ending.Could you please help me.    ^(?=(?:[ ()-]*\d){10})(?:\(\d{2,3}\) ?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{3,4} ?\d{0,10}|^\d{2,3}[ -]?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{0,10})

Comment: You mean to also match whitespace(s) at the start/end of string? Just add " *" after the lookahead. [`^(?=(?:[ ()-]*\d){10}) *(?:\(\d{2,3}\) ?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{3,4} ?\d{0,10}| *\d{2,3}[ -]?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{3,4}[ -]?\d{0,10})`](https://regex101.com/r/oF5gV0/2)

Comment: Thanks but it is only working fine for start of string.I need for end  of string also :)

Comment: I do not know what you input really looks like. Just try adding " *" at the end of the pattern. Maybe even add `space`+`*$` at the end. See https://regex101.com/r/sI7bF0/1

Comment: Hi I want Regex which allow number,space,hypen and parathenisis anywhere with min 10 character and max 20 character.Please help me

Comment: ^([0-9][- ()]*){10,20}$ I am using this but it is not allowing space,() and - in the starting .Only allowing numbers.

Comment: It looks basic: `^[0-9 ()-]{10,20}$`. You overused parentheses (you do not need them) and you separated character classes, quantified one of them with `*` - that disables the length check immediately since it matches zero or *more* occurrences. And the limiting quantifier is set to the whole *sequence* of `[0-9][- ()]*`. One thing is great: you know the hyphen must be at the start/end of the character class :)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this regex :

```
/^((?:\d{2} )?\d{3}[ -]\d{3,4}[ -]\d{4})|(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{10,})/gm
```

You can test it here : https://regex101.com/r/mD0sO7/3

I hope this can help you.

Comment: nice but you're missing `^` and `$`

Comment: @SUMANSINGH What is the problem with it ?

Comment: @Wiktor's answer is good, but still, I don't get how my regex doesn't match your formats. I mean, everything is hightlighted on the demo, right ?

Comment: @Seblor- I missed ^ in expression.It is working fine now.Thanks

Comment: @SUMANSINGH Oh, yes, my bad. I corrected my answer.